# How to remove the character from string in java?

Tags: java, functional-programming

I want to write a program in java to remove the user input word from a `string` and the remove the repeated characters from the `string`.

I have written the code given below:

```
import java.util.*;
public class wordcut {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String line, word;
        Scanner in =  new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the line");
        line = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the word to remove from line");
        word = in.nextLine();
        Boolean found = Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")).contains(word);
        if(found)
        {
            line = line.replace(word, "");
        }
        System.out.println("The line after remove the word is:\n "+line);
        char[] check = line.toCharArray();
        int len = check.length;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(line);
        String r="";
        for(int i=0;i<sb.length()-1;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<sb.length()-1;j++)
            {
                if(line.charAt(i)==line.charAt(j))
                    sb.deleteCharAt(j);
            }
        }
        line = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("After removing repeated character from line:\n"line);
    }


}
```

But I cannot get the output thatI am expecting.

For example, enter the line

```
I love java
```

Enter the word to remove from line

```
love
```

The line after remove the word is:

```
I java
```

After removing repeated character from line:

```
I jav
```

Comment: So you remove one word and then remove all repeated occurrences of characters, what do you expect?

Comment: "repeated character" - yes, you removed the extra `a` from the line, since it had already appeared elsewhere in the line. what else do you expect?

Comment: @Mackiavelli Yes. I hope you got my point

Comment: @Marc B I executed that code. But I cannot get the output

Comment: No, I don't get what you are trying to do... Do you want to remove all occurrences of repeating characters, or remove them so that only one occurrence of the repeated character (like you are currently doing) remains?

Comment: so what ARE you getting?

Comment: @kervin "But I cannot get the output what I am expecting" indicates that the  code does not accomplish what it's meant for. Accordingly it's not "working as intended" and **off-topic** for codereview. For more information, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers

Comment: I think he wants to remove an `a` from `aa` but not from `aba`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String line, word;
        Scanner in =  new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the line");
        line = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the word to remove from line");
        word = in.nextLine();
        Boolean found = Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")).contains(word);
        if(found)
        {
            line = line.replace(word, "");
        }
        System.out.println("The line after remove the word is:\n "+line);
        char[] check = line.toCharArray();
```

do not initialize sb with line.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
```

iterate over that `array` and check if sb contains that `char` if not append it to the string builder

```
for(char ch:check){
    if(!sb.toString().contains(""+ch)){
        sb.append(ch);
    }
}

System.out.println("After removing repeated character from line:\n"+sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### UPDATE

With regards to @Mast comment, you're probably asking for repeated sequential characters to be removed.  `String.replaceAll()` can do this for us.

Pattern explanation:

- `(.)\\1{1,}` means any character (added to group 1) followed by itself at least once
- `$1` references contents of group 1

Code Sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String line, word;
    Scanner in =  new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the line");
    line = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the word to remove from line");
    word = in.nextLine();

    // No need to convert to List or check, replace() does everything for you
    line = line.replace(word, "");
    System.out.println("The line after remove the word is:\n" + line);

    // Remove sequential repeated characters
    line = line.replaceAll("(.)\\1{1,}", "$1");
    System.out.println("After removing repeated character from line:\n" + line);
}
```

Results 1:

```
Enter the line
I love javaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Enter the word to remove from line
love
The line after remove the word is:
I  javaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
After removing repeated character from line:
I java
```

Results 2:

```
Enter the line
I love javaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Enter the word to remove from line
hello
The line after remove the word is:
I love javaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
After removing repeated character from line:
I love java
```

### OLD ANSWER

You don't need to convert your line to a List or check if the word is in the line.  `String.replace()` will do everything for you even if the word is not in the line.  As far as removing duplicate characters, `regex` can take care of that for you.

Regex Pattern breakdown:

- `(.)` - matches any character and puts in group 1.
- `?=` - this is called a positive lookahead.
- `?=.*\\1` - positive lookahead of zero or more characters for the
  first group

Code Sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String line, word;
    Scanner in =  new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the line");
    line = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the word to remove from line");
    word = in.nextLine();

    // No need to convert to List or check, replace() does everything for you
    line = line.replace(word, "");
    System.out.println("The line after remove the word is:\n" + line);

    // Remove duplicate characters
    line = new StringBuilder(
        new StringBuilder(line)
                .reverse()
                .toString()
                .replaceAll("(.)(?=.*\\1)", ""))
        .reverse().toString();
    System.out.println("After removing repeated character from line:\n" + line);
}
```

Results 1:

```
Enter the line
I love java
Enter the word to remove from line
love
The line after remove the word is:
I  java
After removing repeated character from line:
I jav
```

Results 2 (spaces are treated as duplicate characters):

```
Enter the line
I love java
Enter the word to remove from line
hello
The line after remove the word is:
I love java
After removing repeated character from line:
I loveja
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem with your code lies in the fact that you are checking for characters using `line` variable and removing them from `sb` variable. Also you are comparing `i` and `j` variables to the length of `sb` variable. Consider the following case:

Lets say after removal of string you have the line as:

```
"aabb"
```

In your program when `i` is 0 and `j` is 0, `line.charAt(i)==line.charAt(j)` will return true, so it is going to remove the first "a", now the `sb.length` is reduced to 3 from 4. Now in the second loop `i` is 0 and `j` is 1 so again `line.charAt(i)==line.charAt(j)` will return true and remove the second "a". Also `sb.length` has reduced to 2. Now it will exit the loop as `j < sb.length()-1` will return false for `j` value 2 . In the outer loop `i` will attain a value of 1. But the test condition for the `for` loop is `i < sb.length()-1` will return false as `sb.length()` is 2. So the output string would be `"bb"`.

So the corrected version of your for loop should be :

```
    for(int i=0;i<sb.length()-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1;j<sb.length();j++) //<-- you dont want to compare character to itself so j is initialised to i+1
        {
            if(sb.charAt(i)==sb.charAt(j)){ //<-- compare characters of string builders.
                sb.deleteCharAt(j);
                j--;                        //<-- reduce j by 1 to compensate for the reduction of character in sb
            }
        }
```

I hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Yes. It came to know the usage of "sb". Thanks @Blip